# Javascript: Swap a header logo in Wordpress for just two specific web pages

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm somewhat new to writing javascripts and could use a little help. I'm trying to swap a header logo in Wordpress for just two specific web pages on a site. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var url = "website/littlebigfoot/"
if (window.location.href.match("/littlebigfoot/$")) {
$('.footerbox').css("background-color","#0b79a9")
```

Comment: Please post any attempt you have made at writing the code. (I'm not the down-voter).

Comment: How's this different from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714403/javascript-div-styling-for-two-specific-web-pages-on-a-site)?

Comment: Why not just change it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the url of the page.

```
if( document.URL === "www.home.com/about" || document.URL === "www.home.com/contact") {
    console.log('run code')
}
```

That if statement should allow for the code to only be applied to those pages only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL

And I agree with the above answers too, please research and paste code that you've tried also.

Edit: fixed typo